# Where is Action Constraint "Evaluation Time" property on the action panel?

Tags: constraints, panel, actions

I am using version 2.9 and I cannot find the "Evaluation Time" Property for the Action object constraint.

I saw in some videos and posts that it *should* be right under the "Target" property. In the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/action.html) the panel looks just like mine where Evaluation Time is no where to be seen, yet it still explains what it does and what it's for as if there was a way to access it. Is there something I'm missing here?

[image: Action panel showing no Evaluation time]

Comment: Which version blender are you using? On 2.93.5 evaluation time  appears between target and Mix.

Comment: I am using version 2.90.0. I should probably update it to make sure the problem isn't my version.

Comment: I can confirm that updating to 2.93.5 fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from version 2.90.0 to version 2.93.5 fixed the issue!